# CSS height animation of conditionnal div working only on div show

Tags: html, css, angular, css-animations

I have multiple nested `containers` angular bloc that displays using *ngIf conditions.

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="changeType()">Show/Hide type </button>
<div ngClass="{{type ? 'bloc-on' : 'bloc'}}">
  <ng-container *ngIf='type'>
    <p>
      {{type}}
      bla
      bla
      bla
    </p>
    <p>
      bla
      bla
      bla
    </p>
    <p>
      bla
      bla
      bla
    </p>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="changeCat()">Show/Hide cat </button>
    <div ngClass="{{cat ? 'bloc-on' : 'bloc'}}">
      <ng-container *ngIf="cat">
        <p>
          bla 2
          bla 2
          bla 2
        </p>
        <p>
          bla 2
          bla 2
          bla 2
        </p>
        <p>
          bla 2
          bla 2
          bla 2
        </p>

      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
<p> Static bloc</p>
```

In CSS

```
.bloc {
  max-height: 0px;
  visibility: 'hidden';
  transition: max-height 500ms ease-in;
}
.bloc-on {
  max-height: 1000px;
  visibility: 'visible';
  transition: max-height 500ms ease-in;
}
```

Actually the animation is done only when the first condition is `true` then when ngcontainers are false , the animation did not happen

Here's [a reproduction](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-ljteh4?file=src/app/app.component.css)

Comment: If you want to do with jQuery
https://codepen.io/dgwyer/pen/xyNdNb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this Stackblitz I forked from your example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-eptgpv

The problem is that *ngIf removes the elements immediately and there is no element to show the transition.

Instead you can simply hide the elements with CSS:

```
<div ngClass="{{type ? 'simulation-bloc-on' : 'simulation-bloc'}}">
  <div [class.hide]="!type">
    <div>
      <p>
        {{type}}
        bla
```

and for the second block:

```
    <div ngClass="{{cat ? 'simulation-bloc-on' : 'simulation-bloc'}}">
      <div [class.hide]="!cat || !type">
        <p>
          bla 2
```

The .hide class in CSS:

```
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there are no elements to show the transition when we click on the button it is removed immediately so the transition is not working.

But In your example, your `<p> Static bloc</p>` is going behind from your div so make some changes in CSS you can try with it

```
  .simulation-bloc {
    max-height: 0px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }
  .simulation-bloc-on {
    max-height: max-content;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }
```

Thank you :)